# Google App Engine PIL lib TypeError: object of type 'Image' has no len()

Tags: image, google-app-engine

I want to crop an image using images library of google app engine. The code part that i am using for this is the following.

```
                key = self.request.get("blobkey")
                img = images.Image(str(key))
                images.crop(img,0.0,0.0,0.5,0.5)
                resim = img.execute_transforms(output_encoding=images.PNG)

        content = {
        }

        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "image/png"
        self.response.out.write(resim)
```

But when i try to crop an image, it gives such an error.

```
                TypeError: object of type 'Image' has no len()
```

Is there anyone who knows about this error or is there any other way that i can crop an image in python?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at Image [documentation](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/docs/python/images/imageclass.html#Image)

```
class Image(image_data=None, blob_key=None)
```

you forgot to specify the `blob_key` name parameter calling the `Image` constructor:

```
key = self.request.get("blobkey")
img = images.Image(blob_key = str(key)) #You should specify blob_key
images.crop(img,0.0,0.0,0.5,0.5)
resim = img.execute_transforms(output_encoding=images.PNG)
```